# strings get randomly truncated in PHP

Tags: php, string, truncate

I have an issue with a PHP script I'm developing. Sometimes (very rarely, but it occurs) strings don't get concatenated correctly, as fragments of the string get lost during the process, resulting in randomly truncated strings.

This is an example, it's part of the code that gathers the order info and sends it via email to the client (that's why I'm forced to use html tables).

```
$rowList[$rowCode] .= '<tr><td class="lens-price-serv"><small>' . $lang['services'] . ':</small>&nbsp;<strong>' . money_format( '%i', $srvPriceTotal ) . '</strong></td></tr>';
```

The code works just fine. This morning, though, I got an email with the following html (corresponding to the PHP code I posted):

```
<tr><td class="lens-price-serv"><s>Services: <strong>€ 10,00</strong></s></td></tr>
```

I couldn't get the exact html code, this one comes from Chrome's Developer Tools. What I think happened is that the 'small' tag got truncated during string concatenation, becoming an open 's' tag. This tag, without the corresponding closure '/s' tag, got automatically closed by the browser just before closing the 'td'.

This issue is hard to replicate. I tried making a new order using the same parameters, but it worked just fine.

This is the second time this issue presented itself; the first time it was on another part of the code, but the string got truncated as well, resulting in wrong output.

Could this issue be caused by the server? This script is hosted by a shared hosting running Apache 2.2.24 and PHP 5.3.21.

Comment: Be carefull with using " and '. Try using \" if you use the " within ' tags. Hope this helps some.

Comment: @Amir I use .= because I need to gather all the info into one string variable before sending the mail, and since it's a rather long string I prefer to break it into smaller ones.

Comment: @Dieter I'll try, but I've never had a problem with this before.

Comment: It's not appear to be a PHP bug, since there is a opening and close of the `<s>` tag. Did you try to make a search by `<s>` tag in your sources? Also notice that `s` is a valid element with a different semantics from the `small` element. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/s

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$rowList[$rowCode] .= "<tr><td class='lens-price-serv'><small>$lang['services']:</small>&nbsp;<strong>" . money_format( '%i', $srvPriceTotal ) . "</strong></td></tr>";
```

Comment: I'll try editing the code this way and see if the issue will present itself again, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
$rowList[$rowCode] .= "<tr><td class='lens-price-serv'><small>{$lang['services']}:</small>&nbsp;<strong>" . money_format( '%i', $srvPriceTotal ) . "</strong></td></tr>";
```